# integration Web Application on server and windows application on client

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows, web

Is there a way to pass uniqueID of pc to server like MAC address, or IP address of client machine (not router ip or NAT IP)?

I have 1 web application host on ms clouds server and a windows application as listener on every pc in my company.

I want my windows application to react when the user click on the button on the website.
For example a user access the website and click on generate file, the windows listener application where on the same machine the user use to click on website should run the file generation process.

I try to get IP address but it return the NAT IP which is same for all PC. My idea is to get the client ip / MAC and store it to DB and then the listener check if there any process queue on db that belong to its ip.

Is there any other way that I can make the listener run the process when the user click button on the website?